# Regular expression perl grab block of text

Tags: regex, perl

```
Something () {
  X {
    block of text
  }
  Y{
    block of text
  }
  Z{
     block of text
  }
}
```

I am reading line by line and I wan to get the block of text from 'Something' to the last '{'

I am using the regex like below

**/Something {/../}/**

But it will get until this:

```
Something {
  X {
    block of text
  }
```

Can some one help me to grab the whole block of text with regex?

Comment: What is your regex for starters?

Comment: what is the meaning of regex starter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`Regexp::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common) which can match balanced parentheses,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Regexp::Common;

my $re = $RE{balanced}{-parens=>'{}'};
my $s = q[
Something {
  X {
    block of text
  }
  Y{
    block of text
  }
  Z{
     block of text
  }
}
];
print "$1\n" if $s =~ /(Something\s+$re)/;
```

output

```
Something {
  X {
    block of text
  }
  Y{
    block of text
  }
  Z{
     block of text
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursive subpattern for this:

```
/Something \s* ( { (?: [^{}]* | (?-1) )* } )/x
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dF3fP4/1)

However keep in mind it won't work for escaped curly brackets and will break if you have unbalanced brackets.

Comment: what is escaped curly bracket? I put Something () then the regex break

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only want lines with no leading space, i.e.

```
/^Something {/ .. /^}/
```

Comment: Actually there are leading space too and i dont think wanna hard code the white space number as i am not very sure it is consistent all the way

Comment: that may be difficult to do with the .. operator.  Probably easier to just count braces; i.e. while(<>){ $brace++ if m/{/; $brace-- if m/}/; $text .= $_; last if $brace == 0}